# GCC (MingW) + LD generate nearly empty executable. Why?

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, boot

For a specific requirement, I need my binary to fall below 510bytes.

Doing the program in assembler, I get <100 bytes, while adding same code in C++, the resulting code is over 1K. Looking the resulting binary, mostly all ( + 90%) is full of 0x00 characters (Only a few characters at the beginning and end are really populated).

Currently building commands:

```
gcc -Wall -Os -s -Wl,--stack,32 -nostdinc -nostdinc++ -fno-ident -fno-builtin -I. -c -o cppFile.coff cppFile.cpp
nasm -f elf -o main.elf main.asm
ld -T link.ld -o out.elf main.elf cppFile.coff 
objcopy -O binary out.elf out.bin
```

Size of files generated:

1. cppFile.coff = 684 bytes
2. main.elf = 640
3. out.elf = 2707
4. out.bin = 1112

When not linking to the cppFile.coff (with only one empty function)

3. out.elf = 1984
4. out.bin = **31**  (tested and working)

**Why GCC or LD add so many nul charactres?**

**How to remove this empty space?**

```
ENTRY(start)
phys = 0x7c00;
HEAP_SIZE = 0;
SECTIONS
{
  .text phys : AT(phys) {
    code = .;
    *(.text)
    *(.rodata)
  }
  .data : AT(phys + (data - code))
  {
    data = .;
    *(.data)
  }
  .bss : AT(phys + (bss - code))
  {
    bss = .;
    *(.bss)
  }
  end = .;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell, but likely something in the COFF file like alignment. Can you add to your question the output from this command `objdump -x out.elf` when linking with the CPP object file. That should show the sections, their VMA, and LMAs, and alignment.

Comment: Not in any way related to your issue but you shouldn't need any of the `AT`s to specify an LMA(Load Memory Address) in this case since all your sections are one after another (LD ill be able to compute the LMAs here automatically). If you are making a bootloader then you're likely going to want to put the WORD value of 0xaa55 in the last 2 bytes of the first sector.

Comment: I see you are using _GCC_. _GCC_ compilers by default generate 32-bit code. You may be able to use the `-m16` to compile 32-bit code that works in 16-bit real mode but it works best if the code is placed in the first 64KB of memory and it requires segment registers CS=DS=ES=SS=0x0000 . Although the code with `-m16` would run in 16-bit real mode it is actually using 32-bit operands and addresses so won't work on 8086/80186/80286 processors. It is better to change into 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I am reading&trying based on your comments. I will give an answer soon. But I wanted leave a comment to don't give the impression of having abandoned.